# Setup fiber home network with single Router connection to FTTH ISP

Tags: networking, router, isp, fiber, 10gbit

Networking noob here. I have the following network setup at home (north Germany) right now:

[image: Current network setup]

As you see, the ISP ONT inside the top floor of my house has an SC/UPC connector that connects to a Fritzbox 5530 (ISP recommended) through an AON SFP module(LC/UPC). The Fritzbox has only one SFP slot and authenticates with the ISP using the following configuration:

[image: Fritzbox5530 configuration]

IPV6 configuration is as follows:
[image: Fritzbox5530 IPV6 configuration]

My question: What device, with at least two SFP slots, could I replace the Fritzbox 5530 with, that would still authenticate with the ISP giving me internet connectivity, and enabling 10G fiber conectivity within the home network? The following diagram is what I want to achieve:
[image: Target network setup]

All if this, hopefully without having to pay thousands of Euros/Dollars. Is that even possible?

Comment: Does your current setup _not_ give you 10G fiber connectivity within the home network? Is this purely to replace two devices with one?

Comment: Yes, I want to reduce the devices within the network :)